# Formatting decimal columns with LINQtoCSV

Tags: c#, linq, linqtocsv

I need to format a decimal field in a .csv file that I write with the LINQtoCSV library of this format: `95.43000000` for that format `95.43`. I map this field like this:

```
[CsvColumn(Name = "Price", OutputFormat = "C")]
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

which gives me a monetary value `$95.43`. I load the data so that it is brought up to the 6th decimal place, but I need to eliminate strings of zeros at the end:

```
Price = Math.Round(AdjustPrice(x.Price, x.Ticker), 6)
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: The c format is currency with two decimal places. Change the c format according to following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: "of this format: ... for that format" - what does this mean?

Comment: Instead of using the `C` currency formatter, instead use the `F2` fixed point format for your desired output. You can test it like so: `Console.WriteLine($"{price:F2}");`. So in your code it should look like this: `[CsvColumn(Name = "Price", OutputFormat = "F2")]`